# JavaScript Form with radiobuttons

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

i am trying to make a quiz in javascript where i check the answers supplied to the user using radio buttons. it checks the first entry ok but then when it moves to the second question it throws up an undefined type error `cannot read property of undefined` . on this line i have tried messing around with `getElementById` and using document.form but haven't been able to work out why the error is there. the code is a copy and paste of whats used for the first question which works fine! please help!

```
var questionsChosen = new Array();
for (var i = 1;i<16 ;i++ )
{
    questionsChosen[i]= false;
}
function randomQuestion()
{
    var myQuestions = new Array();
    myQuestions[1] = "<tr><td><h4>Which one of these authors wrote and illustrated 'Calvin and Hobbes'?</h4></td></tr><tr><td><input type='radio' name='question1' value='Charles Schultz'>Charles Schultz<br><input type='radio' name='question1' id='correct' value='Bill Watterson'>Bill Watterson<br><input type='radio' name='question1' value='Jim Davis'>Jim Davis<br><input type='radio' name='question1' value='Tommy Peters'>Tommy Peters<br><hr/></td></tr>";

    myQuestions[2] = "<tr><td><h4>In the Calvin and Hobbes Comic, Who was Calvin's annoying neighbour?</h4></td></tr><tr><td><input type='radio' name='question2' id='correct' value='Susie Derkins'/>Susie Derkins<br><input type='radio' name='question2' value='Samantha Jones'/>Samantha Jones<br><input type='radio' name='question2' value='Sally Parker'/>Sally Parker<br><input type='radio' name='question2' value='Sarah Marsh'/>Sarah Marsh<br><hr/></td></tr>";

    for (var k = 1;k<myQuestions.length ;k++ )
    {
        document.write(myQuestions[k]);
        questionsChosen[i]= true;
    }
}

function checkAnswers()
{
    // use boolean to set whether a question has been asked or not. if it has then check here 
    // maybe something like if question1==true
    if (questionsChosen[1]= true)
    {
        var correctAnswer = document.myQuiz.question1[1].value;
        var userAnswer;
        for (i=0; i<document.myQuiz.question1.length; i++) 
        {
            if (document.myQuiz.question1[i].checked==true)
            {
                userAnswer =document.myQuiz.question1[i].value
            }
        }
        document.write("<br><br>Which one of these authors wrote and illustrated 'Calvin and Hobbes'?");
        document.write("<br>Your chosen answer is: "+userAnswer);
        if (correctAnswer == userAnswer)
        {
            document.write("<br>Correct!");
        }
        else document.write("<br>Incorrect... The answer was "+ correctAnswer);
    }


    if (questionsChosen[2]= true)
    {
        var correctAnswer = document.myQuiz.question2.value;
        var userAnswer;
        for (i=0; i<document.myQuiz.question2.length; i++) 
        {
            if (document.myQuiz.question2[i].checked==true)
            {
                userAnswer =document.myQuiz.question2[i].value
            }
        }
        document.write("<br><br>In the Calvin and Hobbes Comic, Who was Calvin's annoying neighbour?");
        document.write("<br>Your chosen answer is: "+userAnswer);
        if (correctAnswer == userAnswer)
        {
            document.write("<br>Correct!");
        }
        else document.write("<br>Incorrect... The answer was "+ correctAnswer);
    }
}
```

`

Comment: This happens when `document.write()` is called after the page has been parsed. It automatically calls `document.open()' which wipes out ALL previous JS and HTML.

Comment: so is there a way for me to get around this? do i just hold the write stmnts untill all the answers are generated?

Comment: just went through it again and changed the document.write() stmnts to write it all to one string that gets bigger. it then prints out at the end in one go! thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If question2 is also an array like question1 you must state the index of the array whose value you would like to retrieve and set as the correct answer. question2 is the array itself. An array cannot have a value, but its elements have values. So it must read question2[1].value, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the line `var correctAnswer = document.myQuiz.question2.value;` to

```
var correctAnswer = document.myQuiz.question2[1].value;
```

put 1,2,3,4 watever is correct answer

Comment: yeh i had that but actually copied in the wrong txt. i was trying EVERYTHING to get it to work. when i put back in the array location it still gives the error!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below code its working perfectly fine.

```
<html><head></head><body>
    <script>
    var questionsChosen = new Array();
    for (var i = 1;i<16 ;i++ )
    {
        questionsChosen[i]= false;
    }
    function randomQuestion()
    {
        var myQuestions = new Array();
        myQuestions[1] = "<tr><td><h4>Which one of these authors wrote and illustrated 'Calvin and Hobbes'?</h4></td></tr><tr><td><input type='radio' name='question1' value='Charles Schultz'>Charles Schultz<br><input type='radio' name='question1' id='correct' value='Bill Watterson'>Bill Watterson<br><input type='radio' name='question1' value='Jim Davis'>Jim Davis<br><input type='radio' name='question1' value='Tommy Peters'>Tommy Peters<br><hr/></td></tr>";

        myQuestions[2] = "<tr><td><h4>In the Calvin and Hobbes Comic, Who was Calvin's annoying neighbour?</h4></td></tr><tr><td><input type='radio' name='question2' id='correct' value='Susie Derkins'/>Susie Derkins<br><input type='radio' name='question2' value='Samantha Jones'/>Samantha Jones<br><input type='radio' name='question2' value='Sally Parker'/>Sally Parker<br><input type='radio' name='question2' value='Sarah Marsh'/>Sarah Marsh<br><hr/></td></tr>";

        for (var k = 1;k<myQuestions.length ;k++ )
        {
            document.write(myQuestions[k]);
            questionsChosen[i]= true;
        }
        document.write("<a href='Javascript:void(0)' onclick='checkAnswers();'>Check Answers</a>");
    }

    function checkAnswers()
    {
        // use boolean to set whether a question has been asked or not. if it has then check here 
        // maybe something like if question1==true
        if (questionsChosen[1]= true)
        {
            var correctAnswer = document.myQuiz.question1[1].value;
            var userAnswer;
            for (i=0; i<document.myQuiz.question1.length; i++) 
            {
                if (document.myQuiz.question1[i].checked==true)
                {
                    userAnswer =document.myQuiz.question1[i].value
                }
            }
            document.write("<br><br>Which one of these authors wrote and illustrated 'Calvin and Hobbes'?");
            document.write("<br>Your chosen answer is: "+userAnswer);
            if (correctAnswer == userAnswer)
            {
                document.write("<br>Correct!");
            }
            else document.write("<br>Incorrect... The answer was "+ correctAnswer);
        }


        if (questionsChosen[2]= true)
        {
            var correctAnswer = document.myQuiz.question2[1].value;
            var userAnswer;
            for (i=0; i<document.myQuiz.question2.length; i++) 
            {
                if (document.myQuiz.question2[i].checked==true)
                {
                    userAnswer =document.myQuiz.question2[i].value
                }
            }
            document.write("<br><br>In the Calvin and Hobbes Comic, Who was Calvin's annoying neighbour?");
            document.write("<br>Your chosen answer is: "+userAnswer);
            if (correctAnswer == userAnswer)
            {
                document.write("<br>Correct!");
            }
            else document.write("<br>Incorrect... The answer was "+ correctAnswer);
        }
    }

    </script>
    <form name='myQuiz'>
        <script>
            randomQuestion();
        </script>

    </form>
    </body></html>
```